# jQuery show a loading image while gif loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, gif

I've got a very simple piece of functionality on my site that shows a static image when the page loads and if you want to see the gif then you hit the image and it loads and starts showing once loaded.

It goes as follows

```
jQuery(".imgGif").each(function(index) {
jQuery(this).css( "cursor", "pointer" ); 
jQuery(this).click(function (index) {
    src = jQuery(this).attr('src');
    var extension = src.substr( (src.lastIndexOf('.') +1) );
     switch(extension) {
        case 'gif':
            jQuery(this).attr('src', src.substr(0, src.length-3) + 'jpg');
            break;
        case 'jpg': 
            jQuery(this).attr('src', src.substr(0, src.length-3) + 'gif');

            break;
        default:
            alert(extension);
            break;
        }
})
});
```

It works and you can see it here, 
http://www.lazygamer.net/xbox-360/has-watchdogs-been-downgraded-since-e3-2012/

However the gifs are 15mb so it takes a while for them to load and start playing, how do I get the image to change to a loading image while we wait so that people know something is happening?

Comment: I'm not sure I got it, but you're saying that you want to use a loadind gif of 15Mb?! If so, it's just insane.

Comment: No I'm loading a 15Mb gif and I want to use a loading image between the static file that loads normally and the gif..

So the page loads with a nice picture, I click it and a loading picture takes its place and then the gif starts when it is done loading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace this code:

```
jQuery(this).attr('src', src.substr(0, src.length-3) + 'jpg');
```

with:

```
var $el = jQuery(this);

//save the original source in a variable
var src = $el.attr('src');

//replace the current source with a loading gif (i.e. http://preloaders.net/)
jQuery(this).attr('src', '/path/to/loading.gif');

//start loading the original image
var img = new Image();

//once the original image is loaded then replace the loading gif
img.onload = function () {
    $el.attr('src', src);
}
img.src = src;
```

Comment: Don't you mean I should change the .gif one to do this? So that it loads the loading gif?     Should I also no change $el.attr to load my large gif instead ?

Comment: You're answer wasn't exactly right but it got me in the right direction... I needed to set the img.src to be the new file I wanted to load.. then in the onload function I set $el's srouce to img's source and it's working.

Comment: Exactly, that's what I suggested.

Comment: Yeah but it's not what the code did.. the code set it back to the original src... but like I said it definitely got it working I just had to change one or two things.. looks awesome now :)

Comment: Oh ok, I thought you need the original image, nervermind, glad it works now.